# Change first option text of select with JS

Tags: javascript

```
<select>
  <option>Option 1</option>
  <option>Option 2</option>
  <option>Option 3</option>
</select
```

I want to replace the text "Option 1" with the text "Select here". Using JS only. But only the first option of the select.

Comment: can you share your code attempt ?

Comment: `document.querySelector("option").textContent = "Select here";` <- Does that work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way to do it! Although, you have to share your attempt code next time. Please read the forum's rules.

```html
<select>
  <option>Option 1</option>
  <option>Option 2</option>
  <option>Option 3</option>
  
  <script>
    (function(){
      document.currentScript.parentNode.firstElementChild.textContent = "Select here";
    }())
  </script>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) to select the first occurence of the element:

```js
document.querySelector("option").textContent = "Select here";
```

```html
<select>
  <option>Option 1</option>
  <option>Option 2</option>
  <option>Option 3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select the first child of the `select` HTML element by first selecting the `select` element

```
const selectElement = document.querySelector("select");
```

since, options are children of `select` then you can select children specifically using array index and change the text.

```
selectElement.children[0].textContent = "Select here"
```

```js
const selectElement = document.querySelector("select");
selectElement.children[0].textContent = "Select here"
```

```html
<select>
  <option>Option 1</option>
  <option>Option 2</option>
  <option>Option 3</option>
</select>
```